# Corner radius delay

Tags: swift, uiview, storyboard, swift4.1

I'm currently setting the corner radius of a UIView via the storyboards user defined run time attributes window.

[image]

When I start the application there is a 2-3 second delay before I see the corner radius getting applied.

This is a new project, so there is only this UIView and nothing.

Any idea why I'm seeing this delay?
I have pinned the view to the leading, trailing, and bottom of the super view. I then have the height set to a constant.

Comment: I replicated your setup, but I don't see this problem. Try to define these attributes in your code instead.

Comment: @the4kman Yeah I tried setting them programmatically in the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.I'm going to try restarting Xcode and my Mac and see if that helps.

Comment: Restarting Xcode alone didn't work, but restarting my Mac did..

Comment: Cool! Write a self-answer to let others know you solved this issue.